# Difference between XmlTextWriter and XmlSerializer?

Tags: c#

I was using `XmlSerializer` when I came across someone using `XmlTextWriter`.

What is the difference between those two?

To me, they serve the same function which is to create XML files. Microsoft website said that `XmlTextWriter` provides a fast, non-cached, forward-only way of generating streams but I don't really know what that means.

Comment: XmlSerializer knows how to serialize an object to xml.  XmlTextWriter knows how to write xml to a stream or file.  Two distinct and unrelated operations.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `XmlTextWriter` class is an object that knows XML. You can use it to generate arbitrary XML documents. It doesn't matter where the data's coming from; you can pull data for XML elements, attributes, and contents along with the actual structure of the XML document from whatever source you see fit, and it doesn't need to match any particular object's structure or data.

On the other hand `XmlSerializer` is an object that knows types. It has the features necessary to analyze a type, extract the important information, and write that information out. It happens to be able to *use* an `XmlTextWriter` object to perform the actual I/O; you can provide your own, or at some level it will always create a similar object to handle the actual I/O. In other words, the serializer object doesn't really know XML per se, nor does it need to. It delegates that work to another object.

> Microsoft website said that `XmlTextWriter` provides a fast, non-cached, forward-only way of generating streams but I don't really know what that means.

- "fast": not slow
- "non-cached": important pieces of information are not stored in memory longer than absolutely necessary
- "forward-only": you cannot revisit parts of the XML document you've already created

That is in contrast to other methods for generating XML documents in which the entire document structure is held in memory as its constructed, and written to a file only once the entire document has been constructed. This is often described as the "document object model", or DOM.

The writer approach tends to be more efficient in performance because the XML data is being generated on the fly, as needed, directly from other in-memory data structures you already have. Because the DOM approach requires the entire file's data and structure to be represented in memory at once, it will usually use more memory, which in some cases can reduce performance (though, frankly, on modern computers and for typical XML documents, this is usually a complete non-issue).

Comment: so lets say I use XmlTextWriter to generate a xml file. Since it's forward only, I won't be able to load the xml file to text box and rewrite the value?

Comment: _"Since it's forward only, I won't be able to load the xml file to text box and rewrite the value?"_ -- yes and no. You can always reload the XML using e.g. `XmlTextReader`. And you can rewrite the value, but you would have to rewrite the entire file at once. Indeed, this is exactly what `XmlSerializer` would do if you deserialize an object from a file, display the object's values in a text box, and then serialize the object to the file again. It's just that the `XmlSerializer` operates at the object level, so you don't have to worry about the underlying XML implementation details.

Comment: ok so if I understand this correctly, if I use XmlSerializer, I can pick a specific node's value to overwrite, but if I use XmlTextWriter, I can't just overwrite a specific value, but must overwrite the entire file if I want to change a single value?

Comment: No, I'm not aware of any way to "pick a specific node's value to overwrite", even using `XmlSerializer`. You can modify "the specific node's value" in your in-memory object graph, but ultimately the entire XML file gets overwritten, whether you use `XmlSerializer`, `XmlTextWriter`, `XmlDocument`, or `XDocument` (the latter two being the DOM-oriented XML authoring classes in .NET).

Comment: so when would you use XmlSerializer over the other or vice versa? Is it as simple as "use XmlSerializer if you are using class and objects"? To me, it seems a lot simpler to use XmlTypeWriter, so I don't know when you would use XmlSerializer.

Comment: Personally, I would not generally use `XmlSerializer` to generate arbitrary XML. I would use it only when I have specific data objects that I want serialized. There are lots of other uses for XML that have nothing to do with serializing individual objects, and for that I would typically use one of the other techniques (but usually not `XmlTextWriter`, just because its efficiency is not usually needed, and it's harder to use). Some people do use a serializer to generate specific XML that otherwise wouldn't be tied to specific objects, but IMHO that can often be more trouble than it's worth.

Comment: To repeat part of Peter’s comment above: “Indeed, this is exactly what XmlSerializer would do if you deserialize an object from a file, display the object's values in a text box, and then serialize the object to the file again. It's just that the XmlSerializer operates at the object level, so you don't have to worry about the underlying XML implementation details.” it seems clear that they’re tools used for different tasks. To convert from an object to xml, you need XmlSerializer. To save the xml to file, you use either, depending on how you want to go about it (DOM or otherwise).